# Trying to utilize "use" tag lightning component, what is the workaround?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am trying to use **USE** tag as its is given in many slds docs,

Here is how it is given in SLDS doc

```
 <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#success"></use>
      </svg>
```

Here is how I tried using

1. Tried using svgIcon component, but no success.
2. Tried HTML but no success

   ```
   <c:svgIcon svgPath="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#success"><c/:svgIcon>
   ```

   [image]

Please let me know what should be used other then "use" tag as salesforce doesn't support that I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightning doesn't currently support svg directly, but you can use [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm) or [lightning:buttonIcon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm) for SLDS icons and button icons, as appropriate. If SLDS wants a button, use a lightning:buttonIcon, and if you just need the image, you can use lightning:icon.

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:success" />

<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:success" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by sfdcfox, use lightning:icon tag. Or else refer the link below to create a svg component:
http://hellosnl.blogspot.in/2017/07/including-svg-in-lightning-component.html